# Can't run Vuetify + Leaflet >> Webpack error

Tags: javascript, vue.js, leaflet, vuetify.js

I followed the instructions from https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue2-leaflet  https://vue2-leaflet.netlify.app/quickstart/#installation

**main.js**
`import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';`

**MyComponent.vue**

```
<template>
..
<l-map
                v-if="showMap"
                :zoom="zoom"
                :center="center"
                :options="mapOptions"
                style="height: 80%"
                @update:center="centerUpdate"
                @update:zoom="zoomUpdate"
                @ready="doSomethingOnReady"
              >
                <l-tile-layer
                  :url="url"
                  :attribution="attribution"
                />
                <l-marker :lat-lng="withPopup">
                  <l-popup>
                    <div @click="innerClick">
                      I am a popup
                      <p v-show="showParagraph">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque
                        sed pretium nisl, ut sagittis sapien. Sed vel sollicitudin nisi.
                        Donec finibus semper metus id malesuada.
                      </p>
                    </div>
                  </l-popup>
                </l-marker>
                <l-marker :lat-lng="withTooltip">
                  <l-tooltip :options="{ permanent: true, interactive: true }">
                    <div @click="innerClick">
                      I am a tooltip
                      <p v-show="showParagraph">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque
                        sed pretium nisl, ut sagittis sapien. Sed vel sollicitudin nisi.
                        Donec finibus semper metus id malesuada.
                      </p>
                    </div>
                  </l-tooltip>
                </l-marker>
</l-map>
...
</template>
```

```
import latLng from 'leaflet'; // https://vue2-leaflet.netlify.app/quickstart/#installation
import { LMap, LTileLayer, LMarker, LPopup, LTooltip } from 'vue2-leaflet';

components: {
      LMap,
      LTileLayer,
      LMarker,
      LPopup,
      LTooltip
}
```

```
data: () => ({
      zoom: 13,
      center: latLng(47.41322, -1.219482),
      url: 'https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
      attribution:
        '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
      withPopup: latLng(47.41322, -1.219482),
      withTooltip: latLng(47.41422, -1.250482),
      currentZoom: 11.5,
      currentCenter: latLng(47.41322, -1.219482),
      showParagraph: false,
      mapOptions: {
        zoomSnap: 0.5
      },
      showMap: false
}
```

Actual Results

vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: Error in data(): "TypeError: leaflet__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_32___default(...) is not a function"

found in

```
<MyComponent> at src/views/apps/deal/MyComponent.vue
       <VMain>
         <VApp>
           <Layout> at src/layouts/full-layout/Layout.vue
             <VApp>
               <App> at src/App.vue
                 <Root>
```

**→ seems latLng function is unknown**

#### Versions

- Leaflet: v1.7.1
- Vue: v2.6.12
- Vuetify: v2.4.0
- Vue2Leaflet: v2.7.0

Answer (score 0):

The import line:

```js
import latLng from 'leaflet';
```

Should have been a named import instead:

```js
import { latLng } from 'leaflet';
```

(Note the curly braces)